# How to configure the linter for formatting space between {{or}} and variables

Tags: eslint, eslint-plugin-vue

I have to configure the linter rules, so that it can detect space in html between "{{ value }}"

for example, this would be ok
`<div>{{ value }}</div>`
and the error would be wrong 
`<div>{{value}}</div>`

I use: eslint-plugin-vue: 5.2.2

What rule is responsible for it?

Comment: i found resolution 
it was enough to change lint configuration  from `'plugin:vue/essential'` to `'plugin:vue/recommended'`

Comment: I found 'vue/mustache-interpolation-spacing' - https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/mustache-interpolation-spacing.md

Answer (score 0):

I found this rule in eslint-plugin-vue library  https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/mustache-interpolation-spacing.md